# Nexus - Proxy repository with no storage

Tags: continuous-integration, nexus, devops, continuous-delivery

I have two instances of Sonatype Nexus.

One of them is installed on a processing-focused machine, in other words, it has no disk space. So, I hold this instance to keep only our lighweight dependencies, such as small jars used by a lot of projects.

The other machine have enough disk space, but it is out of our network. I want to use it to keep the bigger dependencies, the ones we don't use frequently.

That said, I want to create a proxy repository into the first Nexus installation pointing to the installation that hold the biggest artifacts. But I don't want it to download the dependencies from the other, because it would cause a lot of headaches when deal to disk space. Do you guys have any idea on how to do it? I'll clarify, I need a proxy repository pointing to another Nexus installation that that don't download the artifacts when they're requested. Please, help.

Comment: There isn't any way to make a proxy that consumes no space.  But you can keep the space used in control by scheduling a "delete unused components" task under "system/tasks" in the UI.

Comment: Removed the Artifactory tag as this is pure Nexus question. Although, Artifactory does have this feature of only proxying without storing the content... 

Disclaimer, I'm working at JFrog.

Comment: Perhaps make an improvement request on https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS.  This is the first I've heard of anything like this (despite the fact apparently Artifactory does it).